# Получить общий баланс пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql

Так я получаю общую сумму пользователя с **ID 1**, но мне нужно вывести пользователя у которого самый большой баланс.

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM `user_balance` WHERE uid = 1;
```

Таблица:

```
╔═════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ UID ║    NAME     ║   BALANCE   ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║   1 ║ John Smith  ║         500 ║
║   1 ║ John Smith  ║          25 ║
║   2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║          20 ║
║   1 ║ John Smith  ║          20 ║
║   2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║           5 ║
╚═════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Как мне получить такой ответ ?:**

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════╗
║    NAME     ║   TOTALBALANCE   ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ John Smith  ║              545 ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно, как-то так:

```
SELECT `name`, SUM(`balance`) AS `max_balance`
FROM `user_balance` GROUP BY `uid`,`name` ORDER BY `max_balance` DESC LIMIT 1
```